# Uploading via REST API some .exe output files from workflow: got corrupted, file size increases

Tags: powershell, rest, http, github-actions

I have my Github Action "publish":

```
name: publish

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - release-*

jobs:
  test:
   uses: ./.github/workflows/test.yml
   secrets: inherit
  publish:
    name: Publish
    needs: test
    
    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        dotnet-version: [ '8.0.x' ]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: true
          token: ${{ secrets.CHECKOUT_TOKEN }}
      - name: Instalar .NET SDK ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ matrix.dotnet-version }}
      - name: Agregar DevExpress Nuget source
        run: dotnet nuget add source "https://nuget.devexpress.com/..../api"
      - name: Ejecutar build.ps1
        shell: pwsh
        env:
          DISABLE_PROGRESS: 1
          NEXION_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.NEXION_USERNAME }}
          NEXION_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.NEXION_PASSWORD }}
        run: .\build.ps1 -enableOutput
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: release-artifacts
          path: .\build\**
```

The step `.\build.ps1 -enableOutput` is a script which does all the .exe producing, and then uploads to my own website its output via an API, like this:

```
function Get-MultipartBody($boundary, $paths, $fields) {
    $boundary = "`r`n--" + $boundary
    $multipart = @($fields.Keys + $paths) | % {
            $name = if ($paths.IndexOf($_) -ne -1) {'upload_files'} else {$_}
            $contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=`"$name`""
            $contentType = ''
            $data = ''
            if ($name -eq 'upload_files') {
                $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileName($_)
                $contentDisposition = $contentDisposition + "; filename=`"$filename`""
                $contentType = "`r`n`Content-Type: application/octet-stream"
                $bytes = [IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_)
                $data = [Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('ISO-8859-1').GetString($bytes)
            } else {
                $data = $fields.Item($_)
            }
            return $contentDisposition + $contentType + "`r`n`r`n" + $data
        }
    $middle = $multipart -join ($boundary + "`r`n")
    return $boundary + "`r`n" + $middle + $boundary + "--"
}
...
$body = Get-MultipartBody $boundary $files $fields
...

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://my-domain.com.ar/services/release/publish/add" -Method Post -Body $body -WebSession $session -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary" -TimeoutSec 300000 -MaximumRedirection 0
...
```

My problem is that somehow, the files reach my server API, and are stored but they are corrupted, while the step `actions/upload-artifact@v4` stores the files just fine on the action itself.

Just as an example:

The artifact NexionSmartERP-AnyCPU-24.1.0.1.exe is 82M (using actions/upload-artifact@v4)
The same file uploaded to my server API NexionSmartERP-AnyCPU-24.1.0.1.exe is 122M (almost 50% bigger, corrupted)

By the way, the .\build.ps1 script **publishes just fine when running locally** on my host to my server API.

What I'm doing wrong?

Something i’ve found https://stackoverflow.com/a/41995428

Comment: Not clear are good files larger or smaller.  I suspect the files are being compressed (GZIP) and all you need to do is to uncompress.  Are you getting a response status of 200 OK? When a HTTP connection is made a negotiation is made between client and server.  When a HTTP header is not included (like GZIP) you may get different results when code is run on different clients and servers.

Comment: No, the files are .EXE extension (windows installers); files are uploaded to my server (200 OK)

Comment: Change the context-type from application/octet-stream.  Probably causing exe files to get corrupted.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459168/which-mime-type-is-correct-for-the-exe-file  octet stream is for GZIP which is ASCII.

Comment: Tried changing to 'Content-Type: application/x-msdownload': still having the very same problem.

Comment: It is possible a virus checker is corrupting the data.  Is corrupted files larger or smaller than original.  what are the  sizes in bytes?  I would use Beyond Compare to check differences between original and corrupted files to see what is happening.  Open the corrupted file with Notepad++.  Are the character all ascii or combination of ascii and binary.  If all ASCII than the file is GZIP.  Is filename 'upload_files'?  If not, the content type is not being set.

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/110549 @jdweng can you look here please?

Comment: found the PS script.  You are using MIME (multipart).  Each multipart section starts with a two dashes on a new line.  Each Multipart has a Content-Type and the entire Request also have a Content-Type.  See following sample : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)  You should never take binary data and convert to a string it will corrupt the data.  There is no reason to use Encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to avoid building a String from binary data, as @jdweng pointed.

Refactored my PowerShell function to build a temp file, which supports file uploads plus normal fields.

```
function Get-MultipartBody($boundary, $files, $fields) {
    $tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    $UTF8woBOM = New-Object "System.Text.UTF8Encoding" -ArgumentList @($false)
    # Campos
    if ($fields.Keys.Count -gt 0) {
        $sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($tempFile, $true, $UTF8woBOM)
        foreach($field in $fields.Keys) {
            $sw.Write("`r`n--$boundary`r`nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=`"$field`"`r`n`r`n$($fields.Item($field))")
        }
        $sw.Close()
    }
    # Archivos binarios
    if ($files.Length -gt 0) {
        $files | % {
            $sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($tempFile, $true, $UTF8woBOM)
            $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_)
            $sw.Write("`r`n--$boundary`r`nContent-Disposition: form-data;name=`"upload_files`";filename=`"$fileName`"")
            $sw.Write("`r`nContent-Type: application/octet-stream`r`n`r`n")
            $sw.Close()

            $fs = New-Object System.IO.FileStream($tempFile, [System.IO.FileMode]::Append)
            $bw = New-Object System.IO.BinaryWriter($fs)
            $fileBinary = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_)
            $bw.Write($fileBinary)
            $bw.Close()
        }
    }
    $sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($tempFile, $true, $UTF8woBOM)
    $sw.Write("`r`n--$boundary--`r`n")
    $sw.Close()
    $tempFile
}


$boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()
$tempfile = Get-MultipartBody $boundary $files $fields

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://my-domain.com.ar/services/release/publish/add" -Method Post -InFile $tempfile -WebSession $session -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"
```